# Are higher versions of segregated witness script non-standard?

Tags: segregated-witness, non-standard-transaction

My understanding is that only version 0 is defined but other versions are considered valid to allow extensions using soft forks, but are they non-standard at the moment?

Comment: what's the difference between "considered valid" and considered standard in this context?

Answer (score 1):

See @Pieter Wuille's comment, currently all witness programs with versions other than `0` will be rejected as non-standard. See [interpreter.cpp L1447](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L1447)

<strike>**Edit:** As of `v0.16.2`, it appears that all version bytes will at least enter the mempool, provided the rules for version `0x0` (if used) are followed. See [BIP 141 - Witness Program](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#witness-program), [BIP 143 - Restrictions on Public Key Type](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#restrictions-on-public-key-type) and [policy.cpp#L232](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.16/src/policy/policy.cpp#L232)</strike>

Currently, versions bytes higher than `0` will cause the `VerifyWitnessProgram` function to always return true (for future softfork compatibility). Currently version bytes `1-16` are reserved for future use, but, "for any version byte from `0 to 16`, the script must fail if the witness program has a `CastToBool` value of zero."

Comment: Non-standard in this context means that such transactions won't be relayed, enter the mempool, or be mined by common software (despite being valid in blocks, if put there by a miner).

Comment: This is not correct, I'm afraid. The standardness policy consists of various pieces of code, and the most important one is through a verify flag that rejects opcodes/templates intended for future extensions. For mempool acceptable this flag is used, and it will cause script validation for any non-0 witness version